# Google Calendar API doesn't work and Throws a lot of errors

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-calendar-api

I wanted to use the google calendar API to insert events and I found this Codepen: https://codepen.io/www139/pen/mdyoBdm

When I used it on the codepen website, it was working correctly but when I exported, it threw a lot of errors:
[image: A screenshot for the errors],

and when I press the input it throws this error:

[image: The Error that gets thrown when the input is pressed]

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" id="calendarScript"></script>
<input
 type="button"
 value="Create Calendar Event"
 onclick="addCalendarEvent()"
/>
<script src = "script.js"></script>
```

```
function addCalendarEvent() {
  var event = {
    summary: "Google I/O 2015",
    location: "800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103",
    description: "A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.",
    start: {
      dateTime: "2020-01-28T09:00:00-07:00",
      timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: "2020-01-28T17:00:00-07:00",
      timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"
    },
    recurrence: ["RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2"],
    attendees: [{ email: "example@example.com"}],
    reminders: {
      useDefault: false,
      overrides: [
        { method: "email", minutes: 24 * 60 },
        { method: "popup", minutes: 10 }
      ]
    }
  };
  window.googleCalendar.createEvent(event);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  let credentials = {
    scope:
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events",
    clientId:
      "755605534058-mvo5t4ut6di8jj57t37uoohkppi7qrg7.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBK8Eo16V2bQYTYCP0ClJNKNOw7T308j44",
    discoveryDocs: [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"
    ]
  };
  window.googleCalendar = new googleCalendar(credentials);
});

class googleCalendar {
  constructor(credentials) {
    //load dependencies...
    this.gapi = gapi;
    this.gapi.load("client:auth2", init.bind(this));
    let cal = this;
    //create call stack...
    this.callStack = {};
    function init() {
      //authorize api access...
      this.gapi.client
        .init({
          apiKey: credentials.apiKey,
          clientId: credentials.clientId,
          scope: credentials.scope,
          discoveryDocs: credentials.discoveryDocs
        })
        .then(function() {
          cal.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateCallstack);
          function updateCallstack() {
            cal.callStack.func(cal.callStack.args);
          }
        });
    }
  }
  userAuthStatus() {
    if (!this.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get()) {
      this.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
    }
    return this.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get();
  }
  createEvent(event) {
    if (this.userAuthStatus()) {
      let request = this.gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
        calendarId: "primary",
        resource: event
      });
      request.execute(function(e) {
        alert("done");
        console.log(e);
      });
    } else {
      this.callStack.func = this.createEvent.bind(this);
      this.callStack.args = event
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have your script tag in the wrong place or your function is inside another function.

Comment: Can you provide more context? Are these your credentials? (these are getting exposed by providing them here, even though the corresponding client has apparently been deleted). Can you clarify what you mean by `when I exported`? Consider following the JavaScript Calendar [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js).